# How to make only one method to populate Items of a ComBobox as well as a ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, listbox, dry

This procedure below fills a ComboBox with values from a database.

There is also one for ListBoxes, and it's *completely identical* except "box" is a ListBox.

Both CB and LB classes have Items and both inherit ListControl which doesn't have Items.

How can I get rid of the duplicate code there?

```
private void UpdateBox (ComboBox box, string select, string from, string order = "")
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        if (order == "") order = select;
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + select +
            " FROM " + from + " ORDER BY " + order, conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            box.Items.Clear();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                box.Items.Add(dataReader[select]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the other one:

```
private void UpdateBox (ListBox box, string select, string from, string order = "")
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        if (order == "") order = select;
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + select +
            " FROM " + from + " ORDER BY " + order, conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            box.Items.Clear();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                box.Items.Add(dataReader[select]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be able to do: `combobox.Items.Add(dataReader[select]); listbox.Items.Add(dataReader[select]);` in the loop. Can you put the duplicated code, please?

Comment: Updated the post. As for the suggestion, I could've done that if there were just as many CBs as LBs and I wanted to fill the them with the same data. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Items Collections implement IList

So instead of passing the ComboBox/ListBox, you can just pass comboBox1.Items or listBox1.Items to your method.

```
 private void UpdateBox (IList items, string select, string from, string order = "")
```

...

```
 items.Clear();
 while (dataReader.Read())
 {
     items.Add(dataReader[select]);
 }
```

Comment: Just tried this. IList doesn't seem to work without "<T>". I tried "IList<object> items". When I called it with "element.Items" it said "cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.[ComboBox/ListBox].ObjectCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<object>'". With "(Ilist<object>)element.Items" it compiled, but then threw a "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast Objects of type "ObjectCollection" to type "System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Object]"."

Comment: There is System.Collections.IList, and System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>. You have not "using System.Collections", if IList is unknown.
ObjectCollection implements IList, you can check. Hence you can cast to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Holger answer.

For speed performances you can use that refactored:

```
private void PopulateItems(List<IList> listItems,
                           string column,
                           string table,
                           string orderByColumn = "")
{
  using ( var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) )
  {
    connection.Open();
    if ( orderByColumn == "" )
      orderByColumn = column;
    string sql = $"SELECT {column} FROM {table} ORDER BY {orderByColumn}";
    using ( var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection) )
    {
      var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
      foreach ( var items in listItems )
        items.Clear();
      while ( reader.Read() )
        foreach ( var items in listItems )
          items.Add(reader[column]);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var listItemsToPopulate = new List<IList>()
{
  comboBox1.Items,
  listBox1.Items
};

PopulateLists(listItemsToPopulate, "", "", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure this code. You're trying to do too much in 1 function.

Split fetching from the DB from manipulating the control. Now the GetDbItems function is independent - easier to move to a separate class & not bound to the UI directly.

Something like this:

```
IList<string> items = GetDbItems("a", "b", "c");
if (items.Any())
{
    control.Items.Clear();
    control.Items.Add(items);
}

private IList<string> GetDbItems(string select, string from, string order = "")
{
        var result = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            if (order == "") order = select;
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + select +
                " FROM " + from + " ORDER BY " + order, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dataReader[select]);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

- This was just typed into the edit box - I can't guarantee it'll compile. I just wanted to give you a head start.

Comment: *Another caveat, I don't know if this is just sample code you're posting, but I just wanted to mention that the way you're building the SQL query here is wide open to SQL injection. In production, you should really use parameters to build the query. Otherwise make sure you sanitize any user inputs.